# What settings in Babel transpiler I should use with Node.js 4.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Babel transpiler with Node.js (0.12.7). A couple weeks ago Node.js 4.0 was released. And it supports a lot features from ES6 / ES2015 out of the box. I would like to use features supported by Node without Babel and rest available features, just transform to ES5.

What is your recommendation for setup Babel settings? Actually now I just use [Require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_register) on application start.

Comment: read the documentation.

Comment: The title is vague. Based on the question, you're asking how to make Babel pass through some es6 features without transpiling them? A quick glance at the docs didn't turn it up for me, but I might have missed it. I suggest updating the title to "How to transpile some es6 features but not others with Babel", or something.

Comment: Finally I have looked available list of changes for Node.js 4.0 [[here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/)] and in original documentation for babel we already have [options](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/), [using require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) and [list of transformers](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/). But better to use `babel --help` command for getting current list of transformers.
And your main file with require hook should be like:
`require("babel/register")({blacklist: ['es6.blockScoping', 'es6.classes', ...] });`